# ASP.NET send multipart/form-data to Power Automate

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman, restsharp, power-automate

I'm trying to send multipart/form-data to a Power Automate "When a HTTP response is received" trigger action (webhook).

I generate a RestSharp request in Postman like this...

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://prod-122.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/********************************/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=***********************");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.AddFile("file", @"C:\Temp\MyFile.pdf");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Using Postman to send the above works fine, the Power Automate action is triggered, as can be seen in the Power Automate log. 
Using ASP.NET web form to send seems to fail i.e there is no record of it in the Power Automate log.

Without a proxy I get an error in the `response` "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

With a proxy I get an error in the `response` "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected error was protocol related.  Inserting the following line before the `RestClient` is instantiated resovled the issue.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```